# PHPUnit does not work with IntelliJ Idea 13.1.3

Tags: php, unit-testing, intellij-idea, phpunit

I get the following exception while using Idea 13.1.3 with PHPUnit 4.5.0. In some other threads I have seen it was a bug but I this seems to be a problem with latest version also.

```
Testing started at 17:06 ...

Fatal error: Class IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest) in /private/var/folders/yc/cc0z8db95hx4l_d0fvtrx2yxsjjh3x/T/ide-phpunit.php on line 504

Call Stack:
0.0014 854704 1. {main}() /private/var/folders/yc/cc0z8db95hx4l_d0fvtrx2yxsjjh3x/T/ide-phpunit.php:0

Variables in local scope (#1):
$PHPUnitVersionId = *uninitialized*

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: IDEA is the Java IDE.  Most people who write PHP use WebStorm.

Comment: @duffymo I know but I am using the PHP plugin.

Comment: Sounds like your code and the PHP framework aren't matching; somebody added a new abstract method to the framework.  Is that yours?  It's a code problem, not an IDE issue.

Comment: @duffymo no PHPUnit is not mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found from IntelliJ forum that IntelliJ 13 is only compatible with PHPUnit 3.x.
However instead of downgrading, I managed to patch the framework itself for now in [this way](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21666#comment=27-773462).

> 1. go to /plugins/php/lib
> 2. make a backup of php.jar
> 3. Use whatever tool you have to open the file, usually zip or other compress tools or under ubuntu the file roller.
> 4. Go to scripts/phpunit.php
> 5. Modify it, searching for the "IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener" class and adding there the following line:
>
> public function addRiskyTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception
>   $e, $time) {}
>
> 6. save the file and update the php.jar